# Computing Weighted Moving Average in Excel

Tags: excel, data-analysis

I have data points from irregular time intervals

[image]

I need to find the weighted moving average (WMA) for each these data points based on the last k records. Specifically, when computing the WMA for point p, value corresponding to pth record should be assigned a weight of 1 and the weight assigned to each of the k previous points should be inversely proportional to date difference between those points and the pth point. The older a historic record, the lesser the weight assigned to value of that record.

How do I achieve this in Excel?

From my understanding, the key piece I am missing is the ability to transform cell ranges. If theres a way to do this, I could just compute the reciprocal
of date diffs and use that as weight.

**Data Example**
Here is an example illustrating the required computations for just one data point (the one corresponding to 11-Feb-21). This needs to be repeated for all the data points.

[image]

Formulae used:

Weight = 1/(1+ Date diff between 11-Feb-21 and data of current data point)

Weighted Value = Value * Weight

Weighted Average = Sum of Weighted Values/Sum of Weights

Comment: Could you show a typical calculation with actual figures plz? I don't think it would be too hard in principle, but a fairly obvious issue would be that if you included the current point in the moving average the date difference would be zero and the reciprocal of that (which you'd need to work out the moving average weighted in inverse proportion to date difference) would be infinity.

Comment: Is `k` constant?

Comment: @TomSharpe I will add an example shortly to clarify...I am planning to add 1 to the date diff to address the infinity situation you mentioned...my main problem is different though...had this been needed for just one data point, I could have computed intermediate values in another column and used that...but here I need those computed for every single data point

Comment: OK, great. Also, what do you do for the first k rows where you haven't got enough previous points to work out the average? I expect you'll cover that in your example.

Comment: @Jsmart523 my original thought was to include all the past data points in each case...but as I think through it, this can be relaxed (ie, k can be made constant) if that will make things any easier

Comment: @TomSharpe if the number of available previous data points is less than k, we use only those that are available....If it will make things any easier, I am also okay with limiting the computation to only data points that have at least k data points

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, the way I am thinking of doing it would need an N X N array where N is the number of data points so although it should work for a small example, it might not be scalable if you have a lot of data points?

Comment: Max of something like 5K rows doing it this way (using array formula) - VBA could be made more efficient if k is fixed.

Comment: @TomSharpe no problem..there would be a max of 200 data points....yeah I agree VBA might be the way to go...I havent used it before...any code to help get started would be great...I have added a data exaple in the original post above

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your problem?

Assuming 1-Jan-21 is in cell A2,

1. (Value * Weight) D2 = B2 * C2
2. (Running sum of Value * Weight) E2 = IF(ROW()=2,0,E1)+D2
3. (Running sum of Weight) F2 = IF(ROW()=2,0,F1)+B2
4. (WMA) G2 = E2/F2

Now drag the formulas for D:G down your sheet and it should give you your weighted averages.

Better yet would be to use tables. If you highlight your dataset and click **Insert - Table** and add new columns by changing D1 to "VW" and E1 to "RSVW", then

- in D2 you'd want a formula of `=[@Value]*[@[Day of Year]]` (the square brackets mean we're talking about this table, the "@" symbol specifies the current row, and "Day of Year" has extra square brackets because there's a space in the column name.)
- in E2 you'd want a formula of `=IF(ROW()=2,0,OFFSET([@RSVW],-1,0))+[@VW]` because, as long as you aren't making relative cell references by cell addresses like "E1" then the formula won't auto-fill down the column right, so instead we get the same value by using OFFSET to reference "one above the current row's RSVW value"
- yadda yadda

Once you've done that, you're storing those formulas *once per column* instead of duplicated in each cell. As long as you don't put absolute values in those columns you can adjust/change them without having to drag your formula down the column, and you can rename the column titles. Also, I'm not sure if the first way will break when sorting but you use the table formulas then *even deleting a row from the middle of your table* won't break it.

Answer (score 0):

OK well here is the brute force approach of doing it with two big matrices, which should be fine for 200 rows of data and useable up to about 5K. This is with unlimited k, using all previous available rows:

```
=MMULT(IF(TRANSPOSE(ROW(A2:A13))>ROW(A2:A13),0,1/(1+B2:B13-TRANSPOSE(B2:B13))),C2:C13)/
MMULT(IF(TRANSPOSE(ROW(A2:A13))>ROW(A2:A13),0,1/(1+B2:B13-TRANSPOSE(B2:B13))),ROW(A2:A13)^0)
```

[image]